# Using a string in an argument

Tags: c#, string

This is a bit of a noob question, but I'm trying to use a string (myButton), which is set according to the button that called the  method, and trying to use that string inside an argument, but my IDE thinks I'm using the string directly. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GMA
{
     public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
            string myButton;//Currently selected button

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//This will be replicated for every button on the Form
            {
                myButton = "button1";
                SoundRoute();
            }

            public void SoundRoute()
            {
                if ((myButton).Text == string.Empty)//This is the line I'm having trouble with. I want the string of myButton to be converted to button1, button2, etc.
                {
                SoundCall subForm = new SoundCall();
                subForm.Show();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help. I know I could just make a new one for each button, but this is as much for learning purposes as for practical. I've looked all over for the answer but no luck.

Comment: What does "my IDE thinks I'm using the string directly" mean? As opposed to what?

Comment: @BenAaronson It appears the OP tried to cast a string containing `"button1"` to the instance of `button1` on the form.. which caused confusion.

Comment: The IDE gave you a very specific error message about what the problem was with your code. Even if you didn't understand it, there is absolutely no reason for you to have failed to include it in your question. The specific error message is much easier for us to understand than "my IDE thinks I'm using the string directly". If you want help, *provide the information you already have right in front of you* so we'll have it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `sender` argument and pass it to your `SoundRoute` method.. that is actually what its for:

```
public void SoundRoute(object sender)
{
    if (((Button)sender).Text == string.Empty)//This is the line I'm having trouble with. I want the string of myButton to be converted to button1, button2, etc.
    {
        SoundCall subForm = new SoundCall();
        subForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Then your events become:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//This will be replicated for every button on the Form
 {
     SoundRoute(sender);
 }
```

Then, you can have a single event that all buttons are wired up to (since it "will be replicated for all buttons on the form").

Comment: +1. I was about 30 keystrokes and a mouse click away from submitting virtually the same answer (including the info in the last paragraph). You either type faster or saw it a few seconds sooner. :-)

Comment: ...well, I don't like to brag... but I was clocked at 119WPM with 100% accuracy last week :P (random office typing competitions.. :D)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for the help, I've been stuck on this for ages.